# How to boost::fusion::for_each to add type to create an mpl::vector of types?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I'd like to iterate through the member of any fusion struct, add its member's type to a boost::mpl::vector (or set) to create a boost::variant of those types.  Any help is appreciated.

```
struct A
{
    int a1;
    double a2;
    float a3;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    A,
    (int,a1)
    (double,a2)
    (float,a3)
)

struct StructTypes
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T& t ) const 
    {
        // how do I append to a list of types here?
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    boost::fusion::for_each( a, StructTypes() );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I think you can't accomplish what you want using `fusion::for_each`. One very easy alternative that can work is using [`fusion::joint_view`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/view/joint_view.html) to concatenate the `mpl::vector` with your struct (the sequence your struct is adapted to). This joint view can't be used directly in [`boost::make_variant_over`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/make_variant_over.html), but this can be easily solved by using `fusion::result_of::as_vector` to get a `fusion::vector` with the same elements. One problem with this approach (I'm not sure it is really a problem, but it is undoubtedly ugly) is that if you have elements in common between your vector and your struct, the resulting variant will have those elements twice in its list of types. If you want to solve this you can use an `mpl::set` instead of your vector and then use `mpl::fold<A, mpl::set<your types...>, mpl::insert<_1,_2> >::type`. This gives you a `mpl::set` without any duplicated types. You'll need to use `fusion::result_of::as_vector` again in order to use `make_variant_over`.

[Running on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c029c15e98ee2f32)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp> //important: allows compatibility fusion-mpl
#include <boost/fusion/include/joint_view.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/set.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>


#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/insert.hpp>

namespace fusion=boost::fusion;
namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

struct A
{
    int a1;
    double a2;
    float a3;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    A,
    (int,a1)
    (double,a2)
    (float,a3)
)

struct printer
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T) const
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ";";
    }
};


int main()
{
    typedef fusion::result_of::as_vector<fusion::joint_view<mpl::vector<bool,std::string>,A> >::type  types1;
    typedef boost::make_variant_over<types1>::type variant1;

    variant1 a = 3.5f;
    variant1 b = true;

    std::cout << a << " " << b << ". " << fusion::result_of::size<variant1::types>::type::value << " elements in the variant" << std::endl;
    fusion::for_each(variant1::types(),printer());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    typedef mpl::fold<A,mpl::set<std::string,int>,mpl::insert<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>>::type types2;
    typedef boost::make_variant_over<fusion::result_of::as_vector<types2>::type>::type variant2;

    variant2 a2 = 4;
    variant2 b2 = "bla"; 

    std::cout << a2 << " " << b2 << ". " << fusion::result_of::size<variant2::types>::type::value << " elements in the variant" << std::endl;
    fusion::for_each(variant2::types(),printer());
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Btw, if I have multiple classes like A, A1, A2, is it possible for me to "fold" the types info types2 above, without re-typedef?  e.g

`typedef mpl::fold<A,mpl::set<std::string,int>,mpl::insert<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>>::type types2;`<br/>
`typedef mpl::fold<A1,types2,mpl::insert<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>>::type types3;`
boost::make_variant_over<fusion::result_of::as_vector<types2>::type>::type variant2;

Comment: sorry about the edits, I meant:
`typedef mpl::fold<A,mpl::set<>,mpl::insert<...> >::type type1;
typedef mpl::fold<A1,type1,mpl::insert<...> >::type type2;
typedef mpl::fold<A2,type2,mpl::insert<...> >::type type3;
boost::make_variant_over<...<type3>::type>::type variant;

Comment: I'd like to not do a manual typedef, and re-typedef.  If I have a bunch of different types I'd like to add all of them, can I somehow do them generically like calling a function on all of them, then the final type will contain all their member's type?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d208b18e42e98692) is far from perfect, but it seems to work.

Comment: wow, perfect for me.  Thank you so much.  Got to learn more about meta programming!